how to keep the scroll position when scale the VariableSizeList element
I am using react-window https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window VariableSizeList to show some pdf pages, how to keep the scroll positon when scale the pdf pages? now I have tried store the scroll postion into localstorage, when scale the element, tweak the scroll value by plus the scale like this:
const onResize = (size: Size) => {
  if (virtualListRef.current) {
    const scrollOffset = getCurPdfScrollOffset(projId) * projAttribute.pdfScale;
    virtualListRef.current.resetAfterIndex(0, true);
    virtualListRef.current.scrollTo(scrollOffset);
  }
};

the virtualListRef was the VariableSizeList reference. seems did not work as expect. what should I do to keep the pdf scroll postion when the element scaled? on the VariableSizeList I am using initialScrollOffset to get the initial offset like this:
<VariableSizeList
        ref={virtualListRef}
        width={width}
        height={height}
        estimatedItemSize={500}
        initialScrollOffset={getInitialScrollOffset()}
        itemCount={pdf.numPages}
        overscanCount={0}
        onScroll={(e: ListOnScrollProps) => handleWindowPdfScroll(e)}
        itemSize={(pageIndex) => getPageHeight(pageIndex, width)}
      >

the offset value was captured from VariableSizeList onscroll events and stored into localstorage.
